# How long does a Service Worker Subscription last?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I am currently experimenting with service workers and push notifications. I am trying to understand the circumstances in which a subscription expires.

As far as I was aware, once I got my sub id, it would not expire until I stopped the service worker, or unsubscribed. However, this morning I came in to work and found that I was unsubscribed, even though I had left it subscribed last night.

Does anyone have any more specific details about this?

Thanks,

Barry